# List just a first row in a nested dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested

I want list just the fisrt row in the nested Dataframe.

Example:

```
{
"client" : "Mario",
"purchase" : [ 
        {
            "_id" :1,
            "date" : 01-01-2019,
            "product" : "X"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" :2,
            "date" : 05-01-2019,
            "product" : "Y"
        },
        {
            "_id" :3,
            "date" : 08-01-2019,
            "product" : "Z"
        }
    ]
},

{
"client" : "Luigi",
"purchase" : [ 
        {
            "_id" :1,
            "date" : 02-01-2019,
            "product" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" :2,
            "date" : 04-01-2019,
            "product" : "B"
        },
        {
            "_id" :3,
            "date" : 06-01-2019,
            "product" : "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the first purchase like this:

```
Mario 01-01-2019
Luigi 02-01-2019
```

Thanks for help

Comment: where is the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['purchase'] = df['purchase'].apply(lambda row : row[0]['date'])
df = df.rename(columns={'purchase': 'purchase_date'})

print(df)
```

Note: I get the variable `d` by adding `[]` outside what you paste, and also add `""` around the dates.

The result:

```
  client purchase_date
0  Mario    01-01-2019
1  Luigi    02-01-2019
```